# Why is (:hidden) returning true when visible?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do something if the div with the id "err_msg" is hidden. But the code below is returning true when the element is not hidden. Why is that happening?

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var error_msg = $("#err_msg");
        if(error_msg.filter(":hidden")){
            console.log("The error message is hidden");
        }
    });
</script>
<body>
<div id="err_msg">Test </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Any jQuery method like that will *always* return an object, and an object is *never* "falsy".

If you want to check if a jQuery object is empty, check `.length`:

```
if (error_msg.filter(":hidden").length) {
  console.log("it's hidden");
}
```

The library maintains `.length` as if the object were an array, so if the length is zero then there's nothing in it; if it's non-zero then there's at least one element.

Comment: You mean: `and a **jQuery object** is never "falsy"`, because a pure javascript object can be falsy (i.e. ([ ] == false) )

Comment: @AhmadIbrahim no, that's not the same thing. A simple test like: `if ([])` will always be `true`. The `==` operator does all sorts of other things besides a simple test.

Answer (score 2):

Use `is(':hidden')`,

```
error_msg.is(":hidden")
```

.filter() will always return an object. Empty or not, it will be true.

```
$(function () {

    var error_msg = $("#err_msg");

    if(error_msg.is(":hidden")){
        console.log("The error message is hidden");
    }

 })
```

Comment: This isn't bad advice necessarily, but note that when you interrogate a jQuery collection like that, only the first element in the set of matched elements is considered.

Comment: But it is an Id. So only one element is being considered. Right? Or am i missing something?